DOIT ESP32 DEVKITV1 uploading code of wifi scan example to this board
I am trying to upload the code to my ESP 32 but I keep getting this error:
Sketch uses 756385 bytes (57%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1310720 bytes.
Global variables use 43716 bytes (13%) of dynamic memory, leaving 283964 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 327680 bytes.
esptool.py v4.5.1
Serial port COM4
Connecting...

A serial exception error occurred: Write timeout
Note: This error originates from pySerial. It is likely not a problem with esptool, but with the hardware connection or drivers.
For troubleshooting steps visit: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esptool/en/latest/troubleshooting.html
Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 1



Check Serial Port
Check Board Settings
Check Flash Mode and Frequency
If you're using a USB hub, try connecting the board directly to the computer.
Hold down the BOOT button (or FLASH button) on the board while starting the upload process.
Ensure the ESP32 module and any connected peripherals are properly connected and not causing conflicts.
Try uploading a simple example sketch (like the Blink example) to rule out issues with your code.

